# Need the time complexity of this conditional statement method

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, polynomial-time

My idea of the program is :

Input = n sets

objective function ObjFn equals to O(n^3)

Output = the order of n sets

Steps:

1. Applying ObjFn to all n sets
2. Choose the n of the Minimum ObjFn  to be ordered first
3. Eliminate the chosen n
4. Repeat steps 1:3 for the rest n-1 sets
   Note: If there are more than same minimum ObjFn for more than one of the n-1 , clustering all available solutions

I need to check the time complexity of this type of clustering and the overall time complexity of the method.

In addition if there any reference for a similar optimization method to study it.

Thanks in advance.

Example:
If
n= 4
and
the ObjFns are
n1= 30 , n2=50, n3=50, n4=60
then
the outputs are
n1 n2 n3 n4 and n1 n3 n2 n4 .

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23593/755

Answer (score 0):

Seems $O(n^5)$ since the obj function needs to be evaluated $O(n)$ times for each of the remaining sets (of which there are $n$ at the start).  I'm assuming your objective function changes as you add selected sets (i.e. you can't calculate the obj function once per set and store it).

Comment: what about the time complexity of the unknown clustering solutions in this case?

Comment: and What if the calculated Objective function is fixed for all n ? is it still O(n^3)?

Comment: I think it would help if the question were more specifically stated.  I'm just inferring from what you wrote.  I'm thinking about it as you can value how well a set $S$ fits in the current (partial) solution but it costs you $O(n^3)$ to calculate the value.  But more formally laying out your problem statement would help to know how it all goes together, and allow people to make more directed suggestions.